# Delete leading characters from multiple lines with Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have txt-file with 299516 lines - don't ask why!

I need to remove all 110 leading characters from each line, save the next 5 characters and delete the rest of line.

I can do it in EXCEL with "MID()" in the English version.

Unfortunately, Notepad++ does not support repetition counts like ^.{27}

Hints:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions

http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/editors/understanding-regex-with-notepad/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it does as of version 6 (the old regex library that was previously used was replaced with PCRE). Those articles are now out of date.

Using the latest version of Notepad++, find:

```
^.{110}(.{5}).*$
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```